# Log out of NetScaler session in iframe causes loss of asp.net session in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

This isn't really a programming question or a server admin question, more a browser behavior question.

In IE (7 & 8 for sure, testing 9 shortly), I'm visiting site A.com, and that opens an iframe which displays site B.com. I'm logged in to site A (have an asp.net_SessionId cookie), and in the iframe I log in to site B (get a cookie from netscaler NSC_AAAC). When I log out of the netscaler session to site B in the iframe (getting a response that sets a bogus value and an expiration date in the past for that cookie), my next request to site A doesn't send asp.net_sessionID cookie, effectively logging me out of site A.

Is this a browser bug? (I think so because FireFox and Chrome do not behave this way) and if so, what can I do to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the Search Engine. Google seems to steal some cookies for a certain site I use, logging me out despite ticking 'log me in automatically'. Other users complain of the same problem who also use Google. Since using ixquick search engine I haven't experienced the problem.